# DUKPT PIN decryption

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, des, 3des

I have actually been able to carry out a DUKPT data decryption successfully, which was also been confirmed with the BP-Tools - Cryptographic Calculator.

After understanding the differences between the **DUKPT PIN** and **DUKPT DATA** from their respective **Variant Constant** "according to ANSI X9.24, Part 1 document the DUKPT section".

I already changed the index of my keys [Varaint Constant] tallying with the Variant Constant, for the PIN decryption which are **7** and **15** compared to that of the DUKPT DATA which are **5** and **13** which worked successfully.

What i would now want to understand is this, after checking through this [git](https://github.com/meshileya/dukpt/blob/master/src/main/java/com/yinheli/tool/DukptDecrypt.java) used for the DUKPT data decryption

What am i actually getting wrong in this process, or what am i yet to really understand.

Because, trying out the BP-tools DUKPT data decryption, it is really working out with the git provided above, but still having a slight issue to getting the DUKPT pin work out, while been compared with the BP-Tools Calculator.

**The question is:** Is there any other thing to take note of, apart from the Variant Constant when doing a DUKPT PIN decryption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to use the BP-Tools to clarify the output I am getting so as to know the main difference between the DUKPT-PIN and the DUKPT-DATA.

For the DUKPT-PIN: The entered PEK value will be XOR-ed with the value of 00000000000000FF 00000000000000FF (see ANSI X9.24-2004 Appendix A, A.5, page 42) as part of the processing.

For the DUKPT-DATA: As part of the processing, if the data variant **`key = tdesEnc(key, key);`is checked XORing it with  0000000000FF0000 0000000000FF0000**

All i need to do was just to comment out the  `key = tdesEnc(key, key);` which serves the same function as that of the Data Variant which is not used in the process of carrying out DUKPT-PIN